# Angular Swimlane Ngx chart not working locally which works in stackblitz

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ngx-datatable

I am very beginner to Angular.but though I read some of the docs and videos.

I run sample application of angular, but the application which i want to run is 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vertical-bar-chart
.which is working fine on air but when i downloaded it locally .
i run below command after unzip the folder.

1)npm install

2)npm start

while doing start it gives me below error:

info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~prestart: vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~start: vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/asha.koshti/Desktop/vertical-bar-chart/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/asha.koshti/Desktop/vertical-bar-chart
10 silly lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'ng serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/asha.koshti/Desktop/vertical-bar-chart
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v10.10.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vertical-bar-chart@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

My npm and node version is given below:

**node -v**
v10.10.0

**npm -v**
6.4.1

please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

To run Angular, go in the Angular folder. For ex inside myApp and type `ng serve` to run the Angular app. To start learning Angular follow the official docs: [Link](https://angular.io/docs)